# Trying to replace all values matching a pattern in a pandas dataframe with the matched capture groups reversed

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Been trying to replace all values matching a pattern in a pandas dataframe with the matched capture groups reversed. So `Mouse, Mickey` would be replaced with `Mickey Mouse`

Dataframe looks like:

```
+---+---------------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+--+--+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
|   |       0       |  1   |  2   |  3   |  4   |  5   |  6   |  7   |  8   |  9   |  |  |  15  |  16  |  17  |  18  |  19  |  20  |  21  |  22  |  23  |  24  |
+---+---------------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+--+--+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
| 0 | Mouse, Mickey | None | None | None | None | None | None | None | None | None |  |  | None | None | None | None | None | None | None | None | None | None |
| 1 | Duck, Donald  | None | None | None | None | None | None | None | None | None |  |  | None | None | None | None | None | None | None | None | None | None |
+---+---------------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+--+--+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
```

Code:

```
df.replace(r'(.*),\s+(.*)', r'\2 \1', inplace=True)
```

No change in output. What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: I changed the link to the duplicate.  See if the new link is more helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify `regex=True`; By default, *DataFrame.replace* method replaces values literally:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": ["Mouse, Mickey", "Duck, Donald"]})

df.replace(r'(.*),\s+(.*)', r'\2 \1', inplace=True, regex=True)

df
#              A
#0  Mickey Mouse
#1  Donald Duck
```

Comment: Thanks @Psidom! Devil's in the details :)